# VS Code and Python, isort doesn't do its job

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, settings, isort

I've installed `black` and `isort` for code formatting in VS Code.
Black works while `isort` seems not to.

If I run `isort` from the command line there are no problems.

I've tried modifying `setting.json` to no avail. This is the latest version:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    /** "editor.codeActionsOnSave": null */
    /** Enable format on save */
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        /** Pyformat use it's own code action to prevent confliction with other tools. */
        "source.organizeImports.pyformat": true,
        "source.organizeImports.python": true
    },
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    /** "python.sortImports.path": "isort", */
    "python.sortImports.args": [
        "-m 3",
        "-tc",
        "-w 88"
    ],
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
        "--line-length=88"
    ],
...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code only supports a single formatter being used at a time. There is however a workaround described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428648/multiple-formatters-in-visual-studio-code) answer:

```
const firstFormatter = commands.executeCommand('editor.action.formatDocument');

firstFormatter.then(() => myFormat());
```

I'd personally configure it to use black, then attach the command to run the second one.